# Determine if two tables have the same set of keys

Tags: performance, lua, set

I'm using Lua tables as sets by placing the value of the set in the table key and `1` as the table value, e.g.

```
function addToSet(s,...)      for _,e in ipairs{...} do s[e]=1   end end
function removeFromSet(s,...) for _,e in ipairs{...} do s[e]=nil end end

local logics = {}
addToSet(logics,true,false,"maybe")
```

To test if two sets are equal I need to ensure that they have exactly the same keys. What's an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through both tables and make sure that the key has a value in the other. Fail as soon as you find a mismatch, return `true` if you got through both. For sets of size `M` and `N` this is O(M+N) complexity.

```
function sameKeys(t1,t2)
  for k,_ in pairs(t1) do if t2[k]==nil then return false end end
  for k,_ in pairs(t2) do if t1[k]==nil then return false end end
  return true
end
```

Seen in action:

```
local a,b,c,d = {},{},{},{}
addToSet(a,1,2,3)
addToSet(b,3,1,2,3,3,1)
addToSet(c,1,2)
addToSet(d,2,1)
print(sameKeys(a,b)) --> true
print(sameKeys(a,c)) --> false
print(sameKeys(d,c)) --> true
```

*Note testing for `t[k]==nil` is better than just `not t[k]` to handle the (unlikely) case that you have set a value of `false` for the table entry and you want the key to be present in the set.*

Comment: `false` is a valid value in a table, and `if not t2[k]` will miss it.

Comment: @finnw Yes. See the part of my answer from "Note" onwards. Not only does it not apply to the question, but it also is handled by the answer.

Comment: Yes but it's a footnote, and the first version has no advantage over the second so why not use only the second?

Comment: @finnw A fair point; the performance is the same, and saving two characters is not worth it. Edited.

Answer (score 5):

Since you asked about efficiency, I'll provide an alternative implementation. Depending on your expected input tables, you might want to avoid the second loop's lookups. It is more efficient if the tables are expected to be the same, it is less efficient if there are differences.

```
function sameKeys(t1,t2)
  local count=0
  for k,_ in pairs(t1) do
    if t2[k]==nil then return false end
    count = count + 1
  end
  for _ in pairs(t2) do
    count = count - 1
  end
  return count == 0
end
```

Another version avoids lookups unless they are necessary. This might perform faster in yet another set of use-cases.

```
function sameKeys(t1,t2)
  local count=0
  for _ in pairs(t1) do count = count + 1 end
  for _ in pairs(t2) do count = count - 1 end
  if count ~= 0 then return false end
  for k,_ in pairs(t1) do if t2[k]==nil then return false end end
  return true
end
```

**EDIT:** After some more research and testing, I came to the conclusion that you need to distinguish between Lua and LuaJIT. With Lua, the performance characteristics are dominated by Lua's Parser and therefore by the number of source code tokens. For Lua, this means that Phrogz's version is most likely the faster alternative. For LuaJIT, the picture changes dramatically, as the parser is no longer an issue. For almost all cases the first version I showed is an improvement, the second version is probably best when the tables are very big. I would advise everyone to run their own benchmarks and check which version works best in their environment.

Comment: Also, if the lookups are the most expensive part, you could first do a "count-only" check and only if the number of keys matches, compare the keys themself. In any case, you want to benchmark the different alternatives based on your real-life data.

Comment: Lookups are no more or less expensive in Lua for any value.

Comment: In testing with a particular set of sets, the solutions above end up being roughly 1.5x and 2x slower than the accepted answer, respectively. Good ideas, but in the end neither as simple or as performant.

Comment: I tested it with LuaJIT (we are talking performance, right?) and with some test sets my second version is 10x faster than your version. As I said: It depends on the use-case you have.